# java interface - object oriented related

Tags: java, oop, interface

Hi friends I am new in java and trying some example but not getting expected output.

I am applying here dependency injection without spring but not getting expected output.

`BaseballCoach` is dependent on `FortuneServices` for daily fortune and here I am trying to inject `FortuneServices` in a `BaseballCoach` constructor...

Here I am expecting out put "**today is ur lucky day**";
and please tell me where I am doing wrong with some simple language    theoretical explanation...

Thanks in advance

some one help is more valuable...

-->this is the main class which takes

```
        public class DiMain 
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                HappyFortune hf = new HappyFortune();
                BaseballCoach bs = new BaseballCoach(hf);//this is constructor which act as  dependency. 

                bs.getDailyFortune();
            }
        }
```

-->another class which have parameterize constructor

```
    public class BaseballCoach
    {
        private FortuneServices fortunes;

        public BaseballCoach(FortuneServices thefortuneservices)
        {
            fortunes = thefortuneservices;
        }


        public String getDailyFortune()
        {
            return fortunes.getFortune();

        }
    }
```

-->this is Interface class

```
    public interface FortuneServices 
    {
        public String getFortune();
    }
```

-->& this class implement the interface

```
   public class HappyFortune implements FortuneServices 
   {
        public String getFortune()
        {
            return "today is ur lucky day";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to print the output to the console...

Comment: Perhaps you should print the output: `System.out.println(bs.getDailyFortune());`

Comment: you are not outputing anything, that's why you don't get any output.

Comment: thnx i get it...tnx alot @bradimus

Comment: You are getting downvoted because this is not a good question. Though the question is good to you, this question is not good for anyone else. This site is here so others can lookup previous questions and find answers w/o having to ask the same thing.

Comment: Generally, people downvote for [these reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/5743988). Don't take it personally. They are downvoting the question, not you.

Comment: every one learn from there mistakes and me too...next time i am careful..thnx anyws..

Comment: @ajay: you are just learning and want to implement dependency injection? Why don't you start with something a little more basic, like trying to print to output?

Comment: Creating a [mcve] will greatly help you when trying to debug code and get help. In this case, it would have helped you to isolate what the source of the problem was.

Comment: get it friend...mine 1st & silly Question with silly mistake. 
thnx to everyone for reply

Answer (score 3):

The reason you aren't getting any output is because you never provide any. I think your code correctly gets the value "today is ur lucky day", but then it terminates.

Try printing `bs.getDailyFortune()`. Like:

```
System.out.println(bs.getDailyFortune());
```

Or, if you want to keep it as just

```
bs.getDailyFortune();
```

Modify your `getFortune()` method to say:

```
public void getFortune() {
    System.out.println("today is ur lucky day");
}
```

`System.out` is an `OutputStream` (specifically, a `PrintStream`) that lets you output data straight to your console, and it's probably the most commonly used way to display output.

More on output here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html